# Laravel, error when exporting pdf using https protocol

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, dompdf

I have a method that collects a series of records and sends them to a view, to be exported to pdf, I use Laravel and dompdf

```
 /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function pdfExport(Request $request, $id)
{

    $day = $request->get('day');

    ...
    $group_arr = [];


    $pdf = PDF::loadView('front.cars.pdfExport', compact('group_arr'));

    return $pdf->download('cars.pdf');

}
```

And then the view looks like this

```
<style>
    .table{width:100%;margin-bottom:1rem;color:#212529}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#415981">
            <img id="definition-image" width="50%" height="50%" src="{{asset('assets/img/logo/logo.png')}}"><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TEST PDF
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This code works for me on my local machine and on my server if I make the call through http: //, instead if I do it through https: //

I get an error from chrome saying "ERROR: NETWORK ERROR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download() expects a file path. You should probably just use Storage::download